# Index entries with capitalised letters for each word

Tags: indexing, expansion, capitalization

TLDR; I'd like an index (like) command that *fully* expands before executing, so that
`\newcommand{\words}{Some important Words}\indexCMD{\words}`

is *exactly* like
`\indexCMD{Some important Words}` - as if `\words` has fully expanded before `\index` does anything

Plain LaTeX, please.

---

I have a serious problem, which I can't get my head around how to fix:

I'd like to use splitidx to create several indexes at the end of my Bachelor's thesis, however, in order to consolidate and automate some part of the indexing I'm writing a macro, that automatically adds something to the appropriate index if I use an equivalent of `\gls` (glossaries-extra) or `\ac` (acro).
My problem is, that every index entry shall have capitalised words, since I'm mixing German and English, and be correctly sorted.
I'd like to have a command that makes \index{some Words here AND there} equivalent to \index{Some Words Here AND There}

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{splitidx}\makeindex
\newindex[Stichwortverzeichnis]{stw}

\newcommand{\inindex}[1]{#1\sindex[stw]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \inindex{Words are} not as important as other \inindex{words are}.
    
    \printindex[stw]
\end{document}
```

`\newcommand{\inindex}[1]{#1\sindex[stw]{#1@\protect\capitalisewords{#1}}}` is working only superficially since they are sorted how they are called so "some Words here AND there" gets a different entry from "Some Words Here AND There} and they appear twice but identically. I only know LaTeX and only little TeX and would like an answer I can fully understand (by explaining each step) and learn from. I tried \expandafter, \expanded and \noexpand in all shapes but never successfully.

---

Identical problem, different scenario:

`\Acl` and `\Acs` are from the acro package

```
\DeclareAcronym{cfd}{
    short = CFD,
    long = numerische Strömungsmechanik
}
\newcommand{\newglossaryentryac}[2]{    
    \newglossaryentryacKeyCommand[
        id = {#1},
        description = {#2},
        longName = \Acl{#1},
        shortName = \Acs{#1}
    ]
}
\newglossaryentryac{cfd}{Beschreibung}
```

How do I need to modify this, in order for it to be equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\newglossaryentryac}{   
    \newglossaryentryacKeyCommand[
        id = {cfd} ,
        description = {Beschreibung},
        longName = Numerische Strömungsmechanik,
        shortName = CFD
    ]
}
\newglossaryentryac
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid that it's not possible: `\Acl` is not expandable and just *prints* the acronym. Do you need two separate commands? Wouldn't it be easier to use just the `\newglossaryentryac` command, with more keys to perform also the `\DeclareAcronym` command?

Comment: I've tried and tried but either biblatex breaks, it is not compilable, or whatnot. I've tried , using the keycommand package, to define everything separately but due to umlauts (äüö) or `\cite` it just won't work. It seems I need to do everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to define a single command that does both the `\DeclareAcronym` and the `\newglossaryentry` business.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { learex/glossac }
 {
  short .tl_set:N = \l__clearex_glossac_short_tl,
  long  .tl_set:N = \l__clearex_glossac_long_tl,
 }
\tl_new:N \l__clearex_glossac_Short_tl
\tl_new:N \l__clearex_glossac_Long_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\newglossaryentryac}{mmm}
 {% #1 = key, #2 = options, #3 = description
  \keys_set:nn { learex/glossac }
   {% clear all keys
    short={},long={},
    % assign the values
    #2,
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__clearex_glossac_Short_tl
   {
    \text_titlecase_first:V \l__clearex_glossac_short_tl
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__clearex_glossac_Long_tl
   {
    \text_titlecase_first:V \l__clearex_glossac_long_tl
   }
  \use:x
   {
    % acro
    \DeclareAcronym{#1}
     {
      short = \text_expand:n {\l__clearex_glossac_short_tl},
      long = \text_expand:n {\l__clearex_glossac_long_tl},
     }
    % glossaries
    \exp_not:N \newglossaryentry {#1}
     {
      name = \text_expand:n {\l__clearex_glossac_Long_tl},
      \exp_not:n { description = #3\glslink{#1s} },
     }
    \exp_not:N \newglossaryentry{#1s}
     {
      name = \text_expand:n {\l__clearex_glossac_Short_tl},
      \exp_not:n { description = {siehe~\gls{#1}} },
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \text_titlecase_first:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newglossaryentryac{cfd}{
    short = CFD,
    long = numerische Strömungsmechanik
}{Beschreibung}

\newglossaryentryac{tst}{
    short = TST,
    long = test
}{Test}
\newglossaryentryac{ubr}{
    short = übr,
    long = über
}{Über}

\begin{document}

\Acl{cfd} \Acl{cfd} \acl{cfd} \Acs{cfd} \acs{cfd}

\gls{cfd} \gls{cfds}

\Acl{tst} \Acs{tst}

\gls{tst} \gls{tsts}

\Acl{ubr} \Acs{ubr} \acl{ubr} \acs{ubr}

\gls{ubr} \gls{ubrs}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Uppercasing the initial is obtained by using `\text_titlecase_first:n`. The `\use:x` part is because we want the value of the variables, not the variables. With `\text_expand:n` we are sure that special characters are not mangled.

[image]

Comment: I was able to get it to work, I'll only need to expand it to cope with the occasionally appearing foreign form

Comment: What would be a good resource to learn the syntax you used in your answer? I’m very unfamiliar with it.